# Unexpected initial property value with Matlab oop

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, initialization

I have defined a simple class called `MySettings`, which internally holds for others settings defined in a class called `MySubSettings`:

```
%% --- Definition for MySubSettings
classdef MySubSettings < handle    
    properties
        Fifi = 666;        
    end    
end

%% --- Definition for MySettings
classdef MySettings < handle    
    properties
        Riri = 42; 
        Subs = MySubSettings();
    end   
end
```

The first time I instantiate `MySettings` with `s = MySettings();` everything is ok (Property `Riri` is initialized to `42` and `Subs` is an instance of `MySubSettings` with property `Fifi` initialized to `666`) ... So far so good ...

Now if I modify property values and reassign `s` to new instance like this:

```
s.Riri = 0;
s.Subs.Fifi = 0;
s = MySettings();
```

Then inspecting new values for properties in new `s` instance ... I have `s.Riri` which is equal to `42` **(as expected)** ... but `s.Subs.Fifi` is still equal to `0` where I would have expected it to be reinitialized to `666` **(???)**

Why only `Riri` is initialized ? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug ?

*Note: I have the issue with R2013b and R2014b.*

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of MATLAB OOP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My misunderstanding ...

Values assigned to properties in class definition are not **initial values** (like in C# for instance) BUT **default values** and are no longer re-evaluated after the class is first used.

In my example, as `MySubSettings` is a handle class, any value assigned to it becomes the new default for next instances.

This **default value** concept is a bit confusing ... but ok, it was my mistake ... sorry.

Comment: This is correct. To get the behaviour you were expecting, assign the initial value for `MySubSettings` within the constructor of `mySettings`, rather than as a default property value. For a criticism of this design of MATLAB OO, see @Yair 's [recent article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handle-object-as-default-class-property-value) on his UndocumentedMATLAB blog, and for a defence of it see the comments to the article from me and Dave Foti.

Comment: @SamRoberts Thanks for these clarifications, I was indeed wondering why to have such 'default value' concept and not just simply 'per instance initialization'.